# Property of natural numbers involving the sum of digits

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

How can you prove that every natural number $M$ or $M+1$ can be written as $k + \operatorname{Sum}(k)$, where $\operatorname{Sum}(k)$ represents the sum of the digits of some number k.

Example:
$$
248 = 241 + \operatorname{Sum}(241) = 241 + 2 + 4 + 1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Each term in the sequence $k + \mbox{Sum}(k)$ either increases by 2, or decreases by some amount.

Why does that tell you that the image of $k + \mbox{Sum}(k)$ must include either $M$ or $M+1$?

---

**Proof of Hint:** If the last digit is not 9, then $k$ and $\mbox{Sum}(k)$ will both increase by 1, hence their sum increases by 2. If the last digit is 9, then $\mbox{Sum}(k)$ will decrease by at least 8, hence their sum decreases by sum amount.

Comment: I have no idea... So to be clear, I like math problems that require a smart solution, not a complicated one. I am a java developer, so I don't have much experience with number theories... And I've found this problem an interesting one

Comment: This is the smart solution. First, do you agree with the hint? If so, what are the implications of the hint? It doesn't involve Number Theory.

Comment: Yes, I agree, if we add 1 to k, the final sum increases with two... but still I don't have a clue...

Comment: The sum could decrease, like going from $k=9$ to $k=10$. But, assuming that the final sum always increases by 2, do you see why the image must include either $M$ or $M+1$? Now, account for the fact that the sum might decrease by some amount.

Comment: I still have no idea... so what? in some cases, the final number will decrease with 2 if we decrease k with 1 or it may increase with an amount.

Comment: K, try thinking about it this way. You want to walk on a series of stepping stones numbered 1 to 100. Each step, you can either walk forward 2 steps, or walk backwards any amount of steps. Can you explain why you must step on either stone 50 or 51?

Comment: because k was increased with 1. If the last digit of k is 9 and we increase k with one, the final sum will decrease with an amount. But still don't have a clue about a mathematic demonstration of this property

Comment: @gabi Can you try the question I stated in the above comment? I've written up the proof of the hint.

Comment: is because you step on every second stone and after the 9th step, you will go back with some positions and then go forward with 9 steps (18 stones)

Comment: @gabi Given that you accepted the answer, I take it that you now understand how the logic behind the problem.